# Proving $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ is not complete

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain.

> **How can I prove that $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ (with the usual topology) is not sequentially complete?**

I don't think I have ever seen a proof of this claim. I guess the idea is to construct a sequence of functions with increasing supports and small differences, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: It may be easier to draw a sequence of pictures to convince yourself. For example, here is a sequence of smooth functions on $[0,1]$ converging to a discontinuous function on $[0,1]$: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/23972/18/content/chebfun/examples/approx/html/Convergence_03.png

Comment: @Neal: This sequence will not be a Cauchy sequence in $C_{c}^\infty((0,1))$ since the derivative and all the higher order derivatives explode near the origin.

Answer (score 7):

Let us do it for $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ first. With the help of $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$, we can construct, for every $n$, a $C^\infty_c$ function $f_n$ such that $f_n(x)=0$ for $|x|\geq n+1$, and $f_n(x)=1$ for $|x|\leq n$.

Now for every compact $K$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $K$ is bounded so there exists $N$ such that $K\subseteq [-N,N]$. So for all $n,m\geq N$ and all $x\in K$, we have $f_n(x)=f_m(x)=1$. Hence $\sup_K|f_n^{(j)}(x)-f_m^{(j)}(x)|=0$ for all $j$ and all $n,m\geq N$.

So this a Cauchy sequence for the topology of compact convergence. But the pointwise limit is the constant function equal to $1$, which is not compactly supported. So $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ is not sequentially complete.

Working with $e^{-\frac{1}{\|x\|^2}}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and with balls instead of intervals yields a very similat proof for $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

To do the case $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$, we need a [compact exhaustion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhaustion_by_compact_sets) of $\Omega=\bigcup_{l\geq 1}K_l$ such that $K_l$ is contained in the interior of $K_{l+1}$ for every $l$. Then we construct for each $l$ a $C^\infty_c$ function $f_l$ such that $f_l=1$ on $K_l$ and $0$ on $K_{l+1}^c$. This is more difficult. It can be done by convolution. Still with the help of the exponential function. This sequence is Cauchy again, but converges pointwise to the constant function equal to $1$.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question: is $\{f_n\}$ Cauchy with respect to the topology induced by the seminorms $||\cdot||_N$ (where $||f||_N$ is the sum of supremums of derivatives of order $\leq N$)?

Comment: @comp Take $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ and $f_n$ as above. Then if you are talking of the sup over all $\mathbb{R}$, then the sequence is clearly no Cauchy as $\|f_{n+2}-f_n\|_\infty =1$ for all $n$. You need to take these seminorms over compact subsets of $\Omega$. You can restrict to countably many of them by exhaustion. Then yes, as I said above, the sequence is Cauchy with respect to this topology.

Comment: and how can I construct a non-converging Cauchy sequence with respect to the topology induced by the seminorms $||\cdot||_N$? (adding it to your above answer would be highly appreciated)

Comment: @comp What is $\|\cdot\|_N$? Sum of sups over $\Omega$ of all $\|D^\alpha f \|$ for $|\alpha|\leq N$?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: @comp Then you can't find such an example because $C^\infty(\Omega)$ is (sequentially) complete with this topology. So any Cauchy sequence will converge in $C^\infty(\Omega)$. So your question amounts to: is $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ closed in $C^\infty(\Omega)$ for the topology of uniform convergence on $\Omega$? For $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$, the closure is the subspace of all functions in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that all derivatives tend to $0$ at $\pm\infty$. And this is of course not equal to the subspace of compactly supported smooth functions.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant to ask. How can I see that the closure of $C_c^\infty (\mathbb{R})$ has the form you just mentioned? and also, what would be the analogous claim for general $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @comp If you write down what it means that $g_n$ compactly supported converges to $g$, you easily see that $g$ tends to $0$ as well as its derivatives. Conversely, every such function $g$ can be approximated by considering $g_n=f_n\cdot g$ where the $f_n$'s are the functions above. In a general $\Omega$, the condition for the closure would be: $f$ and its derivatives are arbitrarily small outside of some compact.

Comment: @comp In the discrete case, you are in $\ell^\infty$. Compactly supported functions are the sequences which are eventually zero (ie with finitely many nonzero terms). Their closure is $c_0$, the sequences which tend to $0$.

Comment: @comp Does this answer all your questions now?

Comment: Actually I have two more questions (please excuse my rusty analysis skills): 1. If $||g_n-g||_N \rightarrow 0$ (for every $N$) for compactly supported $g_n$, how do you show that all of $g$'s derivatives tend to $0$ at $+- \infty$? 2. Is there a nice explicit example of a Cauchy sequence of compactly supported functions that converge (with respect to the seminorms $||\cdot||_n$) to a non compactly supported function?

Comment: @comp 1. Take $\epsilon>0$. There is $n$ such that $\|g_n-g\|_N<\epsilon$. Let $K$ be the support of $g_n$. for every $x$ outside of this compact, and for every $|\alpha|\leq N$, we have $g_n(x)=0$ as well as all its derivatives, so $\|D^\alpha g(x)\|=\|D^\alpha (g-g_n)(x)\|\leq \|g-g_n\|_N \epsilon$. In the case $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$, the complement of a compact contains some neoghborhood $(A,+\infty)$ of $+\infty$ and $(-\infty,-A)$ of $-\infty$. Restrict to these and you get your $0$ limits at $\pm \infty$.

Comment: @comp 2. For every non compactly supported function $g$ which tends, as well as all of its derivatives, to $0$ at $\pm\infty$, the sequence $g_n=f_n\cdot g$ (with $f_n$ as above) is compactly supported and converges to $g$ with respect to the seminorms $\|\cdot\|_N$. In particular, it is Cauchy. You can not make this  much simpler than that, actually. This takes functions of the type of $f_n$, which are somehow the most simple examples of nontrivial compactly supported smooth functions. If you want to make it slightly more concrete, pick an explicit $g$. Say $g(x)=1/(1+x^2)$.

Comment: Regarding (2), if you take $f_n$ as above, then we know that $f_n=1$ in $[-n, n]$ and $f_n=0$ outside of $[-n-1, n+1]$. If you want to show that $||f_n \cdot g-g||_N \rightarrow 0$ for every $N$, then you have to say something about the behavior of $f_n$ in $(-n-1, -n) \cup (n, n+1)$, no? i.e. how do you bound the derivatives of $f_n \cdot g-g$ on $(-n-1, -n) \cup (n, n+1)$?

Comment: @comp Yes, absolutely. The usual construction has $0\leq f_n\leq 1$ in between $[-n-1,-n]$ and $[n,n+1]$. And the derivatives are bounded too. Indeed, $f_n$ there is a translation of a $C^\infty$ function on $[0,1]$, so the $f_n$ and their derivatives are uniformly bounded on $\mathbb{R}$. The same is true on $\Omega$.

Answer (score 5):

The answer depends on what you mean by ''the usual topology''. Dieudonne and Schwartz invented LF-spaces to have a complete locally convex toplogy on 
$\mathscr D(\Omega)=C^\infty_c(\Omega)$.

Anyway, $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ endowed with the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets of all derivatives is not complete because it is dense in $C^\infty(\Omega)$ (with the same topology) but clearly different.

Answer (score 0):

Convolve a continuous non-differentiable function with a $C^{\infty}$ family of approximations to the identity. Each convolution will be $C^{\infty}$ but the limit won't be.

Comment: Why will this sequence of convolutions form a Cauchy sequence in $C^\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

We illustrate it in the case $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$.
Take a nonzero function $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ whose support is small and concentrated near $0$,
and consider the sequence
\begin{equation}
\varphi_k(x) = \varphi(x) + 2^{-1}\varphi(x-1) + \ldots + 2^{-k}\varphi(x-k),
\qquad k=1,2,\ldots.
\end{equation}
Obviously, this sequence is Cauchy with respect to the seminorms $\|\cdot\|_{C^m(\mathbb{R})}$,
but the support of the limit function is not compact.